# convert cell to a list of element separated by comma MATLAB

Tags: matlab

var is 1x6 cell

```
var = 

'a'  'b'  'v'  'g'  'd'  'r'
```

I would like to convert it to obtain a list with sparated comma
'a','b','v','g','d','r'

any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines will do it:

```
c = {'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'r'};
d = [c',[repmat({','},numel(c)-1,1);{[]}]]';
e = [d{:}]
```

returns:

```
e = a,b,v,g,d,r
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)

```
>> c={'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'r'}

c = 

    'a'    'b'    'v'    'g'    'd'    'r'

>> s=cell2mat(c)

s =

abvgdr
```

Comment: I need to add comma between 'a','b'

Comment: @lola huh ? You do realize that `['a','b']` is nothing but `ab` ?

Comment: Commas can be added like so: `s(1:2:end*2)=s;s(2:2:end)=','`

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Yeah nice !

Answer (score 1):

Much nicer, from Matlab 2013a onwards:

```
>> c = {'a', 'b', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'r'};
>> strjoin( c, ', ')

ans =

'a, b, v, g, d, r'
```

Answer (score 0):

Clumsy one-liner:

```
cell2mat(strcat(var, [mat2cell(repmat(',',1,length(var)-1), 1, ones(1,length(var)-1)),{''}]))
```